# How to read the POST data inside the template in JSREPORT

Tags: jsreport

I have the following request to the jsreport engine:

```
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                url: "http://localhost:5488/api/report",
                data: {
                    template: {
                        shortid: "ry6HoQRee"
                    },
                    data: {
                        "D": "5"
                    }
                },
                success: function (s) {
                    window.open("data:application/pdf,base64," + escape(s.responseText));
                },
                error: function (s) {
                    console.log(s);
                }
            });
```

However I can't find a way to read it inside the report template:

```
<span>{{data.D}}</span>
```

How do I refer to the data object that is inside the POST body

Answer (score 1):

jquery doesn't support binary responses like pdf. You should rather use XMLHttpRequest:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:5488/api/report', true)
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + window.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(xhr.response))));
    }
}
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    template: {
        shortid: 'Syeopu_xe'
    },
    data: {
        'D': '5'
    }
}))
```

Example of reaching data using handlebars templating engine

```
<span>{{D}}</span>
```

Additionally...
You may also take a look at jsreport official [browser client library](http://jsreport.net/learn/browser-client). It wraps the XmlHttpRequest calls into more elegant calls:

```js
jsreport.serverUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

var request = {
  template: { 
    content: 'foo', engine: 'none', recipe: 'phantom-pdf'
   }
};

//display report in the new tab
jsreport.render('_blank', request);
```

or in async fashion

```js
jsreport.renderAsync(request).then(function(res) {
  //open in new window
  window.open(res.toDataURI())

  //open download dialog
  res.download('test.pdf')
});
```